# Recursion array unexpected print value in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

Why does this print `1,1,2,3,4,5` instead of `1,2,3,4,5`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(int a[5], int n)
{
    if(n > 0) {
        print(a, --n);
    }

    printf(" %d", a[n]);
}

int main()
{
   int n, a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
   print(a, n);
   return 0;
}
```

And how would you code it to print 1,2,3,4,5 using recursion in that manner ie traversing from the last?

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: Debugger.............

Comment: Just for kicks, try passing `n-1` as your second parameter in your recursion, rather than changing it via pre-decrement. And note, you'll have to change something else too (left as exercise).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig got it (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you decrement `n` after the comparison in the `if` condition `n > 0`.

When `print(a, 1)` is called, the comparison `n > 0` is true. Then `n` is decremented and, the recursive call is done and `print(a, 0)` evaluated. That fails the comparison and prints `a[0]` once. Then back in the calling function, `a[0]` is printed another time, since the local `n` after decrementing is also equal `0`.

One way to fix it is to decrement `n` before doing the comparison with zero.